# Перевод одной из всплывающих подсказок ссылки "править"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Почему-то не переведён хинт "*You have too many pending edits. Further edits cannot be submitted until prior edits have been approved*"

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Утвердил такой перевод:

> У вас слишком много правок, ожидающих проверки. Новые правки не могут быть предложены, пока предыдущие не будут утверждены.

Будет доступно на сайте после подгрузки Transifex и последующей сборки.

Comment: Очень здорово. Спасибо!